# Different behavior for specific clients

Tags: python, django, settings

I am developing a system that uses a large number of clients.
Some clients want specific behavior from system, for example: different html code or different reports or they want to skip some commands execution.
To specify this behavior I use code like this:

```
if sender.id == 123:
    do_something()
```

Now I have lots of strings with "if"'s and it really prevents code read. Is there any pattern to solve this problem? In general, I'm looking for the way in which it was possible to separate the logic from the unique conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use decorators. When I have part of code specific to some clients, I wrap it with function that contain decorator which I placed in file "decorators.py". Example:

```
view.py

def some_fuction(request):
    do_some_usual_stuff()
    ...
    @do_specific_stuff_decorator
    def do_specific_stuff(sender):
        return sender.price1 + sender.price2

    value = do_specific_stuff(request.sender)
    ...

decorators.py

def do_specific_stuff_decorator(do_specific_stuff)
    def inner(sender):
        #sender foo doesn't need to pay price2 in some cases
        if sender.name = 'foo':
            price = sender.price1
        else:
            price = do_specific_stuff(sender)
        return value
    return inner
```

This usage of decorators reminds you that this part of code contains specific befaviour for some clients but it's clear to read most important code.

Comment: As an aside, wouldn't it be a better idea to base this on groups rather than individuals? Django has robust support for groups of users, and it sounds like a bad idea to hard-code specific users into t. I would create a group for people for whom the application should behave differently so that they can be easily added to it (it can be done programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

If it is purely presentation (templates) you could specify specific templates for the different user behaviors.
I would also advice to not check on userid but to use some kind of extra model to extend the user model. So the data can be edited without changing the code.